# XMLHttpRequest within service worker

Tags: php, json, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm trying to create a push notification system on chrome. 
I have a php that fetches data from mysql and echoes a JSON, now I'd like to call a function getJsonCode() that it's activated when a push notification arrives and reads the JSON data.

Within my service worker I've created the standards functions. The problem is that when I create getJsonCode with a XMLHttpRequest it tells me it's not defined

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  self.skipWaiting();
  console.log('Installed', event);
});
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  console.log('Activated', event);
});
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {  
  console.log('Push message', event);
  getJsonCode();
  );
})

getJsonCode() {
  codeRequest= new XMLHttpRequest();
  codeRequest.open('get', 'myfileWithJson.php', true);
  codeRequest.send();
  dataJSON = codeRequest.responseText;
  console.log('rispostaJSON');
}
```

Is it possible to call an external file like this within a service worker or are there some kind of limitations? Because I don't get why this isn't working

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of `XMLHttpRequest`, you can use the new [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). `XMLHttpRequest` has been deprecated and is not available in the service worker scope.

There's an example of exactly what you want to achieve in [this ServiceWorker Cookbook recipe](https://serviceworke.rs/push-get-payload.html).

Comment: So apparently XMLHttpRequest isn't supported by Service Workers?

Comment: @AbhinavSingi yep, I've written that in the second sentece of my reply.

Comment: Is this still accurate? Here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker it is stated: "Workers may use XMLHttpRequest for network communication, but its responseXML and channel attributes are always null. (fetch is also available, with no such restrictions.)""

Comment: @nvirth that's true for normal workers, but not for service workers. XMLHttpRequest is not exposed for service workers, in the spec (https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/) you can see `[Exposed=(Window,DedicatedWorker,SharedWorker)]`.
If you are not convinced, take a look at https://github.com/whatwg/xhr/issues/19, https://www.fxsitecompat.dev/en-CA/docs/2015/xmlhttprequest-is-no-longer-available-in-service-workers/, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=931243.

Comment: @MarcoCastelluccio and how to use fetch api on development pc using self signed SSL (https://mylocalsite/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use fetch() instead of XHR,as fetch() is a new API which allows you to make requests similar to XHR's, but has a simpler / friendly API.Read more about fetch [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjGxpKd78zMAhVCco4KHYGoA3IQFggqMAI&url=https://gauntface.com/blog/2015/02/11/fetch-is-the-new-xhr&usg=AFQjCNFS49c58Lr2V8iFEkFB_EPQZ1JviA). Try this:-

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) { 
    console.log('Push message', event);
  event.waitUntil(
fetch('/myfileWithJson.php').then(function(response){
return response.json();
}).then(function(data){console.log(data);
    return self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
      body: data.body,
      icon: 'images/icon.png',   
      tag: data.url
    
    });
}));
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately `fetch` is not a complete replacement for `XMLHttpRequest`, particularly the scenario of large uploads: `fetch` still offers no way of getting upload/download progress information, while `XMLHttpRequest` does.