# XMLHTTPREQUEST chrome extension not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am unable to send data from Chrome extension background script using XMLHTTPREQUEST , I have up and running wampserver, I also tried external links such as google.

*What does it do :*

> User enters a permission defined tab, background script waits for hot
>   key,when pressed a content_script is launched and generates a string,
>   the string is sent back to the background script, then the background
>   script should receive the string and send it to a php file, the php
>   file should print hello, its made simple just to try see where is the
>   problem, later php will have more code.
>
> But its completely not working!

**UPDATE**

> I tried to pack the extension then run it by drag and drop, it doesn't
>   launch php script.
>
> I tried to uninstall chrome, restart and then install it again but
>   with no luck.
>
> I have also allowed **--allow-file-access-from-files**

**UPDATE 2**

> I am receiving the following error in debug mode:
>
> **extensions::sendRequest:41: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'callback' of undefined{TypeError: Cannot read property 'callback' of
>   undefined**

**Manifest.json**

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Extractor",
  "version": "1",


  "description": "Extract from 144",
  "icons": { "16": "logo16.png",
           "48": "logo48.png",
          "128": "logo128.png" },


        "page_action": {
          "default_icon": {                    
            "16": "logo16.png",           
            "48": "logo48.png",           
            "128": "logo128.png"            
          },
          "default_title": "Extractor"          
        },

  "background": {

    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches" : ["https://www.msn.com/*"],
      "js" : ["content_script.js"]
    }
  ],
 "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "https://www.msn.com/*",
    "activeTab",
     "http://localhost/*"

  ],
  "commands": {
           "toggle-feature": {
            "suggested_key": {
              "default": "Ctrl+Shift+1",
              "windows": "Ctrl+Shift+2"
            },

            "description": "Extract now"
          }
        } ,
"web_accessible_resources": ["content_script.js"]

}
```

**Background.js**

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
 if (command === "toggle-feature") { 
 chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
     for(var i = 0; i<tabs.length;i++) {
           chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {"file": "content_script.js"});
     }
   });
  }
}); 

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(message, sender, sendResponse) {

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost/test/test.php");
    xhttp.send(message.url);

  });
```

**content_script.js**

```
var url = 'this is just test' ;
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ 'url' : url });
```

**test.php**

```
echo "hello";
```

Answer (score 3):

`XMLHttpRequest` does not work in background scripts since a background script is a service worker:

See related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37114241/6942857

Answer (score 0):

You only able to make XHR Request from chrome extension to URL you defined in your `manifest.json` in your code, you should add `http://localhost` to your `manifest.json`

```
 "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "https://www.msn.com/*",
    "activeTab",
     "*://*/*",
     "http://localhost/"

  ],
```

This permission `"*://*/*",` is not valid. You must specify a protocol (http or https)

---

**More Info:**

- [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest in Chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission)

Comment: added alert it works, but the php file doesn't os I guess there is a problem with xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check in your code if there's [`chrome.extension.sendRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-sendRequest) which was already depracated since Chrome 33. Please use [`runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) instead.

In addition to that, [Simple one-time requests](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple) states that, if you only need to send a single message to another part of your extension (and optionally get a response back), you should use the simplified runtime.sendMessage or tabs.sendMessage.

And, sending a request from a content script looks like this:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

On the receiving end, you need to set up a `runtime.onMessage` event listener to handle the message.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
```

Furthermore, it was noted that:

> The `sendResponse` callback is only valid if used synchronously, or if the event handler returns true to indicate that it will respond asynchronously. The `sendMessage` function's callback will be invoked automatically if no handlers return true or if the `sendResponse` callback is garbage-collected.

For more information on how to send requests and to setup event listener, you may want to check [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).